# Nginx SSL inside a docker container

Tags: nginx, docker

I have configured a Docker container to run Nginx and setup the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file as shown below

```
server 
{
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

 root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 index index.php index.html index.htm;

 server_name example.com;

 location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;   
        include fastcgi_params;
 }

}

server 
{
 listen 443;

 root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 index index.php index.html index.htm;

 server_name example.com;

 ssl    on;
 ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;


 location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }


location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;   
        include fastcgi_params;
 }


}
```

I map the /etc/ssl/certs & /etc/ssl/private folders on the host when I run the docker container

```
docker run -dt -p 8080:443 -p 8081:80 -v /t-base/log:/var/log/nginx -v
/etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs -v /etc/ssl/private:/etc/ssl/private nginx

Docker ps shows

Up n minutes 0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp 0.0.0.0:8080->443/tcp <container-name>
```

and the nginx error log file inside the mapped /t-base/log folder stays empty.

```
docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/bash
```

followed by

```
service nginx status
```

just comes back and says that nginx is running.

All of the above would indicate that everything is working correctly.  However, I find that whilst I am able to browse to

```
http://example.com:8080
```

turns up the default page

```
https://example.com:8081
```

has the Chrome showing me its default "sad smiley" error page.  I cannot see what I might be doing wrong here.  I'd much appreciate any help.

Comment: Your run command has it backwards from your tests? 8080=ssl, 8081=nonssl.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have interchanged the ports. According to this command line `-p 8080:443 -p 8081:80`, you should do:

`https://example.com:8080` note this is http**s**

and

`http://example.com:8081`

This should work