# Docker with Nginx - Https not working

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker

I'm relatively new to using Docker. I set up a Docker container, localy, with Nginx, PHP and Mysql. I can access the IP from the VM (http://192.168.99.100/) and everything works fine.

However, when I go to https://192.168.99.100/, Chrome puts the smiley face and says ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

How can I make Nginx enable the SSL certificate for the environment?

I'm using Windows 10, and the VM uses Virtualbox, **not** Hyper-V

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920852/nginx-ssl-inside-a-docker-container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https works with respect to **domain name** not **ip**, so you can organise https://example.org access, but you cannot organise ssl access to https://123.45.67.89.

As possible solution, if you have certificates (self-signed or real) for domain `example.org`, you can:

1. Add to hosts file (Windows C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts or Linux /etc/hosts) line like
   `192.168.99.100 example.org`
2. Then, add those ssl files to nginx configs and run your app.
3. Now, if you will try to access https://example.org you will get secure connection to 192.168.99.100

Answer (score 1):

You need to have,

In the `vhost`:

```
server {
       listen 443 ssl;
       listen 80;
       ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
       ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
       ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/site.com.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/site.com.key;
       ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
       ssl_session_timeout 10m;
}
```

In the `nginx.conf`:

```
map $scheme $fastcgi_https {
default off;
https on;
}
```

Hope this helps.